# How to access PFUser.Current() on watch app

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, apple-watch, parse-server

I am using Parse and I want to be able to access the current user on my watch. There is a guide on sharing data between a host app and extensions but the function `enableDataSharing(withApplicationGroupIdentifier:, containingApplication:)` is marked as available. I guess I misunderstood and Watch Extensions are not considered App Extensions. Is there another way to access the current user on the Watch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of digging and pursuing multiple options I found out that Watch Apps are completely separate from iOS Apps and can no longer share KeyChain Access. This is probably why the built in Parse solution no longer works. Fortunately Watch Connectivity is pretty secure so I think it's safe to send the session token over from iOS and use PFUser.become to log in.

In the watch app:

```
guard WCSession.default.isReachable else { 
   print("Phone is not reachable")
   return
}

WCSession.default.sendMessage(["Request": "SessionToken"],
                                        replyHandler: (user, error) in {
    guard let token = response["Response"] as? String else { return }

    // there is a version of PFUser.become() with a success callback as well
    PFUser.become(inBackground: token) 
}
```

in iOS (class that conforms to WCSessionDelegate protocol):

```
public func session(_ session: WCSession,
                    didReceiveMessage message: [String: Any],
                    replyHandler: @escaping ([String: Any]) -> Void) {
    // Respond to 'Request' message with sessionToken
    if let _ = message["Request"], let sessionToken = PFUser.current()?.sessionToken {
        replyHandler(["Response":  sessionToken])
    } else {
        // Either user is not logged in, or this was not a 'Request' message
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow!  if you want to open an issue on the iOS SDK OR better, suggest a change in the docs that would be nice. If keychain sharing don’t work on the watch, we shall also probably remove it from the codebase!

Comment: Well I'm not 100% sure this is the case. I did see in the sdk though that the relevant lines in ParseClientConfigurations.h are marked with PF_WATCH_UNAVAILABLE so it looks like you guys have already handled it. I suppose it was my mistake for not understanding that the Watch was not considered an extension. If there was a suggestion to be made I guess it would be to add a note in the docs (DOES NOT WORK FOR WATCH) for guys like me .